# Will an infinite union of rational numbers will the real line?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers, rational-numbers

Consider $\mathbb{R}$ as the underlying metric space with the usual metric. Suppose we construct sets:

$I_1 = \mathbb{Z}$

$\displaystyle I_2 = \{\ldots, -1, -\frac{1}{2}, 0, \frac{1}{2}, 1, \ldots\}$

$\displaystyle I_3 = \{\ldots, -1, -\frac{2}{3}, -\frac{1}{3}, 0, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3}, 1, \ldots\}$

$\ldots$

Now let $I = \cup_{n = 1}^{\infty} I_i$. Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, does $I = \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: No.  Notice that $I$ is the countable union of countably many sets, each of which are countable, and so by theorem we have that $I$ must be countable as well.  $\Bbb R$ is uncountable.  You will have that $I=\Bbb Q$ though.

Comment: What would you say I have misunderstood when I stated that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I'm not sure if you've misunderstood anything except maybe what the $=$ sign represents in your final line or perhaps what $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_k$ represents for some family of sets $(A)_k$

Comment: Maybe you want $I$ to be the [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(topology)) of $\bigcup_{i\in\mathbb{N}} I_i$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $I$ is just $\mathbb{Q}$. So you're simply asking whether there is an irrational number. Or if you prefer:

> Where does, say, $\sqrt{2}$ occur in your $I_n$s?

More generally, "$A$ is dense in $B$" in no way implies, or even should suggest, that $A=B$.